# Как определить временные границы работы интервального планировщика Python?

Tags: python, cron, scheduler

С помощью библиотеки `APScheduler` использую фоновые задачи `BackgroundScheduler`. У него есть метод `add_job()`, при помощи которого указываю интервал в виде `add_job(..., 'interval', hours=1)`. Задача, переданная в `add_job()` будет вызываться каждый час, однако как реализовать систему, при которой задача будет вызываться каждый час с условных 10 часов утра до 21 часов вечера? Т.е., каким образом задать границы работы интервального планировщика?

Comment: судя по документации, вы используете неверный триггер. вам нужен не interval, а cron. https://coderslegacy.com/python/apscheduler-tutorial-advanced-scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

Для такой задачи нужно использовать крон, а не интервал. Но, тем не менее - неточное значение минут/секунд вы указать не сможете.

```
sched.add_job(job, 'cron', hour='10-21', minute='*/7', second='30')
```

[Документация](https://coderslegacy.com/python/apscheduler-tutorial-advanced-scheduler/#cron-trigger)

---

*UPD. Обновлено по просьбе автора.*

**hour='10-21'** - Запускать каждый час с 10 до 21

**minute='*/7'** - Запускать каждые 7 минут.

**second='30'** - Запускать по достижению 30 секунд.

---

***Пример с BlockingScheduler:***

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler
from datetime import datetime

sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone='Europe/Moscow')

def job():
    print(datetime.now().time())

sched.add_job(job, 'cron', hour='9-10', minute='*/1', second='5')
sched.start()
```

Запускает задачу каждую минуту и в 5 секунд.

---

Из этого следует что отталкиваясь от **шедулера** вы можете запускать задачу в фиксированное время в интервале. С возможностью запускать внутренний интервал повторений. Но отсутствует возможность - содавать сдвиги через неточные значения. И с какой то стороны это логично, если подумать.

Вывод, используйте используйте точные значения в интервале минут/часов/секунд. Каждые 450 секунд сделать не получится. Зато получится 420 и 480.

---

Тем не менее, никто не мешает вам сделать так)

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone='Europe/Moscow')

def job():
    sleep(449)
    print(datetime.now().time())

sched.add_job(job, 'cron', hour='10-21', second='*/1')
sched.start()
```

Comment: Мне необходимо выполнять задачу каждые 450 секунд в течении с 10 часов до 21. В Вашей примере как это используется?

Comment: В изначальном вопросе, у вас не написано каждые 450 секунд) но добавил)

Comment: Нельзя устанавливать на 450 секунд? Это ж целое вложение в промежуток.

Comment: Вы не понимаете принцип работы cron. Почитайте документацию. И заодно прочитайте максимальные значения для аргументов функции создания задачи.

Comment: Вы правы, на момент ответа не бы ознакомлен с cron. Однако исходя из Вашего же ответа, Вы указываете на возможность использования секунд (надо было догадаться, что Вы о переводе таковых в целое число минут).